# check in pandas if one value in a data frame is NaN and replace it with 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
        EO  EW  Inc20   Inc100
bike    6   4.0  7      5
other   1   NaN  1      1
```

I want to replace the NaN value to Zero. and I have written the following code:

```
for column in df:
    df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), column] = 0
df
```

it works well and changes the NaN to Zero, but it also changes the value of the first column as well.
so I have this result:

```
        EO  EW  Inc20   Inc100
bike    6   4.0 7        5
other   0   0   1        1
```

but I want to have:

```
        EO  EW  Inc20   Inc100
bike    6   4.0 7        5
other   1   0   1        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need only replace if exist one missing value create mask for count missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with `sum` and filter in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `fillna`:

```
print (df)
       EO   EW  Inc20  Inc100
bike    6  4.0      7     5.0
other   1  NaN      1     NaN
other   1  NaN      1     1.0

m = df.isna().sum().eq(1)
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].fillna(0)
```

Or create mask only for one missing values per columns chaining masks and replace in [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m = df.isna() & df.isna().sum().eq(1) 
df = df.mask(m, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
       EO   EW  Inc20  Inc100
bike    6  4.0      7     5.0
other   1  NaN      1     0.0
other   1  NaN      1     1.0
```

Because [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) replace all missing values:

```
df1 = df.fillna(0)
print (df1)
       EO   EW  Inc20  Inc100
bike    6  4.0      7     5.0
other   1  0.0      1     0.0
other   1  0.0      1     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to jezrael's answer, if you want to change value in only one column

```
df['EW'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```